# Redmine can't get emails

Tags: redmine

I can't get work Redmine Helpdesk plugin. All settings are from its manual, the string is:

```
/usr/local/bin/rake -f /var/lib/redmine/Rakefile --silent redmine:email:receive_imap \
  RAILS_ENV="production" \
  host=myhost port=993 username=redmine password=mypass ssl=true \
  project=test-proj1 folder=INBOX \
  move_on_success=processed move_on_failure=failed \
  no_permission_check=1 unknown_user=accept
```

I'm getting an error:

> Net::IMAP::NoResponseError:  The destination mailbox could not be found.

Although new emails in the mailbox mark as read.

I've modified the command and now I'm getting an error in production.log

> An unexpected error occurred when receiving email: uninitialized constant MailHandler::HTML

Comment: If I send mail from my gmail account, the task creates! Why doesn't it want to use my internal address?

Comment: maybe you don`t have imap? Maybe smtp?